# How Do I Scroll My BackGround Image In Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I was Wonder How I Could Scroll mY background image in pygame

I have a moving object I want it to scroll when that object is moving
here is a video of the background image right now [video](https://gyazo.com/97afc68a47c714c46666f5d390804488)
right now I am just blitting the background image

```
def redrawwindow():
    window.blit(bg,(0,0))
```

here is my full code

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

#this is screem height
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

#know we put screem name
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs Flappy Bird Game")

#player class
class bird:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self.bright = [
            pygame.image.load("killers50.png"),
            pygame.image.load("killers51.png"),
            pygame.image.load("killers52.png"),
            pygame.image.load("killers53.png"),
 
                           
                              ]
        self.bleft = [
            pygame.image.load("ms1.png"),
            pygame.image.load("ms2.png"),
            pygame.image.load("ms3.png"),
            pygame.image.load("ms4.png"),
 





                          
                              ]
        self.bright = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//15,image.get_height()//15)) for image in self.bright]
        self.bleft = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//15,image.get_height()//15)) for image in self.bleft]
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.speed = 5
        self.Walking = 0
        self.vel = 5
        self.color  = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.direction = "down"

                # this makes the enemy move right and left
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        if self.Walking + 1 >= 33:
            self.Walking = 0

        if self.vel > 0:        # left
            window.blit(self.bright[self.Walking % 3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.Walking += 1
        else:                   # right
            window.blit(self.bleft[self.Walking % 3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.Walking += 1

class platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.pipis = pygame.image.load("pip.png")
        self.pipis = pygame.transform.scale(self.pipis,(self.pipis.get_width()//3,self.pipis.get_height()//3))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft=(self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.pipis,self.rect)

class pip:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.pipis = pygame.image.load("pipo.png")
        self.pipis = pygame.transform.scale(self.pipis,(self.pipis.get_width()//3,self.pipis.get_height()//3))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft=(self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.pipis,self.rect)


#player and enemy
white = (255,255,255)
bird1 = bird(0,400,50,50,white)

red = (255,48,48)
platform1 = platform(600,300,150,50,white)
platform2 = platform(800,200,150,50,white)
platform3 = platform(1100,300,150,50,white)
platform4 = platform(1300,400,150,50,white)
platform5 = platform(1500,300,150,50,white)
platform6 = platform(1800,200,150,50,white)

# ROUND 2
platform7 = platform(2200,300,150,50,white)
platform8 = platform(2400,200,150,50,white)
platform9 = platform(2600,300,150,50,white)
platform10 = platform(2700,400,150,50,white)
platform11 = platform(2900,300,150,50,white)
platform12 = platform(3200,200,150,50,white)

# rOUND 3
platform13 = platform(3400,300,150,50,white)
platform14 = platform(3600,200,150,50,white)
platform15 = platform(3800,300,150,50,white)
platform16 = platform(4000,400,150,50,white)
platform17 = platform(4200,300,150,50,white)
platform18 = platform(4400,200,150,50,white)

# ROUND 4
platform19 = platform(600,300,150,50,white)
platform20 = platform(800,200,150,50,white)
platform21 = platform(1100,300,150,50,white)
platform22 = platform(1300,400,150,50,white)
platform23 = platform(1500,300,150,50,white)
platform24 = platform(1800,200,150,50,white)

platforms = [platform1,platform2,platform3,platform4,platform5,platform6,platform7,platform8,platform9,platform10,platform11,platform12,platform13,platform14,platform15,platform16,platform17,platform18,platform19,platform20,platform21,platform22,platform23,platform24]

# sceond pip

pip1 = pip(600,-160,150,50,white)
pip2 = pip(800,-270,150,50,white)
pip3 = pip(1100,-170,150,50,white)
pip4 = pip(1300,-170,150,50,white)
pip5 = pip(1500,-170,150,50,white)
pip6 = pip(1800,-270,150,50,white)

# ROUND 2
pip7 = pip(2200,-160,150,50,white)
pip8 = pip(2400,-270,150,50,white)
pip9 = pip(2600,-170,150,50,white)
pip10 = pip(2700,-170,150,50,white)
pip11 = pip(2900,-170,150,50,white)
pip12 = pip(3200,-270,150,50,white)

# ROUND 3

# rOUND 3
pip13 = pip(3400,-160,150,50,white)
pip14 = pip(3600,-270,150,50,white)
pip15 = pip(3800,-170,150,50,white)
pip16 = pip(4000,-170,150,50,white)
pip17 = pip(4200,-170,150,50,white)
pip18 = pip(4400,-270,150,50,white)


# ROUND 4

pip19 = pip(600,-160,150,50,white)
pip20 = pip(800,-270,150,50,white)
pip21 = pip(1100,-170,150,50,white)
pip22 = pip(1300,-170,150,50,white)
pip23 = pip(1500,-170,150,50,white)
pip24 = pip(1800,-270,150,50,white)

pips = [pip1,pip2,pip3,pip4,pip5,pip6,pip7,pip8,pip9,pip10,pip11,pip12,pip13,pip14,pip15,pip16,pip17,pip18,pip19,pip20,pip21,pip22,pip23,pip24]#window




class orb: 
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)

        




class particleAndPoint:  
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        
particleAndPoints = []
# this is the orbs
orb1 = orb(1500,100,50,550,white)
orb2 = orb(2600,100,50,550,white)

orbes = [orb1,orb2]
platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
platformList = []
level = [" ",
             "                                       ",
             "                                                      ",
             "                                                                                                                     ",
             "                                                                p                 p                              p                     p                p                               p                                      p                      p                  p         p                 p                            p                    p                   p                    p                 p                    p                    p",
             "                                                                                                                                                             ",
             "                                                                                                                                                            ",
             "                                                                                                                                                    ",
             "                                                                                                                                                               ",
             "                                                                                                                                                                  ",
             "                                                                                                  ",]
for iy, row in enumerate(level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "p":
            new_platforms = particleAndPoint(ix*10, iy*0, 10,1010,(255,255,255))
            particleAndPoints.append(new_platforms)





# the score text
font = pygame.font.Font('Candarai.ttf',60)
score = 0
loltext = font.render("" + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
lolrect = loltext.get_rect()
lolrect.center = ((130,60))

# wow sound anime
wowsound = pygame.mixer.Sound("wows.wav")
explodesound = pygame.mixer.Sound("partexplode.wav")

class particle:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.x_vel = random.randrange(-10,13)*1
        self.y_vel = random.randrange(-10,-1)*1
        self.lifetime = 0
    def draw(self,window):
        self.lifetime += 1
        if self.lifetime <30:
            self.x -= self.x_vel
            self.y -= self.y_vel
            pygame.draw.rect(window,(232,255,24),(self.x,self.y, 16,16))
# draw the screen things
def redrawwindow():
    bg = pygame.image.load("bgs.png")
    window.blit(bg,(0,0))
 
#player draw
    bird1.draw()
    for platform in platforms:
        platform.draw()
    for pip in pips:
        pip.draw()
    for particleAndPoint in particleAndPoints:
        particleAndPoint.draw()
    window.blit(loltext,lolrect)
    for orb in orbes:
        orb.draw()
    for particle in particles:
        particle.draw(window)


fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
particles = []
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False



    # if player collides with the obsticles add 1 to the player and delete the obstacle
     
                

    for one in range(len(particleAndPoints)-1,-1,-1):
        if bird1.rect.colliderect(particleAndPoints[one].rect):
            score += 1
            bird1.speed += 0.2
            del particleAndPoints[one]
            explodesound.play()
            loltext = font.render("" + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
            lolrect.center = ((130,60))
            for x in range(60):
                x, y = bird1.rect.center
                particles.append( particle( x, y ) )

 



        # if ball collides with player1 show the particles
        # if ball collides with player1 show the particles
    if bird1.rect.colliderect( orb1.rect ):
        for x in range(60):
            wowsound.play()
            explodesound.play()
            x, y = bird1.rect.center
            particles.append( particle( x, y ) )

        
    if bird1.rect.colliderect( orb2.rect ):
        for x in range(60):
            wowsound.play()
            explodesound.play()
            x, y = bird1.rect.center
            particles.append( particle( x, y ) ) 
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # bird moving
    bird1.x += bird1.speed
    if not bird1.isJump:
        bird1.y += bird1.speed
        bird1.isJump = False

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            bird1.isJump = True


        
        # this part lets you jump on platform
        collide = False
        for platform in platforms:
            if bird1.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
                collide = False

            
            # this makes the player fall down up to 
            if bird1.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                bird1.isJump = False
                bird1.JumpCount = 10
                bird1.y = 500 - bird1.height

        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                bird1.isJump = True
            bird1.fall = 0


    else:
        if bird1.JumpCount > 0:
            bird1.y -= (bird1.JumpCount*abs(bird1.JumpCount)) * 0.2
            bird1.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            bird1.JumpCount = 10
            bird1.isJump = False


    # this scrolls my screen right
    if bird1.x > 300:
        
        bird1.x -= bird1.speed
        for platform in platforms:
            platform.x -= bird1.speed
            
        for pip in pips:
            pip.x -=bird1.speed
        for particleAndPoint in particleAndPoints:
            particleAndPoint.x -= bird1.speed
        for orb in orbes:
            orb.x -= bird1.speed



            
    redrawwindow()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

I want the background to keep scrolling right because my player is always moving right Thank YOu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to draw the background twice in a tiled mode. Add a variable which defines the offset of the background `bg_shift`. Compute the offset in relation to the width of the background by the `%` (modulo) operator (See [Binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)). Finally *blit* the background twice:

```py
bg_shift = 0

def redrawwindow():

    bg_width = gb.get_widht()
    bg_offset = bg_shift % bg_width 
    
    window.blit(bg, (-bg_offset, 0)) 
    window.blit(bg, (bg_width - bg_offset, 0))
```

You have to change the variabel `bg_shift` in the main application loop dependent on the movement of the bird.

```py
bg_shift += bird1.speed
```

You can even try to move the background with a different speed, which gives a nice perspective effect. For instance:

```py
bg_shift += round(bird1.speed / 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

To scroll the background image, you'll have to blit the background image twice, then move each image. When each image moves out of the screen, reset their position to the back of the other image. Here is the code of what exactly I'm talking about

```
#import the pygame library
import pygame

#create our screen and pygame time object
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1024,576])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#load the background image
bg = pygame.image.load("./Data/sky_background/bg.png")


x1 = 0 #sets the first tile's x position to 0
x2 = bg.get_width() #sets the second tile's x position to right-hand side of x1

#mainloop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
    #fill the screen
    screen.fill("white")
    #blits the two tile
    screen.blit(bg, (x1,0))
    screen.blit(bg, (x2, 0))
    #move each image tile
    x1 -= 8
    x2 -= 8
    #reset each tile's position when they move out of the screen
    if x1 <= -bg.get_width():
        x1 = x2+bg.get_width()
    if x2 <= -bg.get_width():
        x2 = x1+bg.get_width()
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I hope this helps a lot. If you ever need any help, feel free to ask :)